# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No suitable constructor found for entity type 'HealthCheck'

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I get this error when trying to add something on my db through EF Core.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No suitable constructor found for
>   entity type 'HealthCheck'. The following constructors had parameters
>   that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind
>   'hctype' in 'HealthCheck(string title, string hctype, string link)'.'

This is my HealthCheck class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Application.Models
{
    public class HealthCheck
    {
        public HealthCheck(string title, string hctype, string link)
        {
            Title = title;
            HCType = hctype;
            Link = link;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string HCType { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My RepositoryContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Application.Models;

namespace Application.Repository
{
    public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=healthcheck;Integrated Security=True");
        }

        //public DbSet<HealthCheck> HealthChecks { get; set; }
        //public DbSet<UserHealthCheck> UserHealthChecks { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<HealthCheck>().ToTable("HealthCheck");
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserHealthCheck>().ToTable("UserHealthCheck");
        }
    }
}
```

My Repository

```
using Application.Models;

namespace Application.Repository
{
    public class Repository
    {
        public void InsertHealthCheck(HealthCheck healthCheck)
        {
            using (var db = new RepositoryContext())
            {
                db.Add(healthCheck);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where "InsertHealthCheck()" is being called from

```
[Route("/api/HealthCheck/Website")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult WebsiteStatus([FromBody] WebsiteDataModel websiteData)
        {
            HealthCheck data = new HealthCheck(websiteData.Title, "Website", websiteData.Url);
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(websiteData.Url);
                HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                HttpStatusCode HealthCheckStatusCode = myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode;
                myHttpWebResponse.Close();
                return Ok(HealthCheckStatusCode);
            }
            catch(UriFormatException)
            {
                return Ok("Check url.");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Ok("400");
            }
            finally
            {
                repository.InsertHealthCheck(data);
            }
        }
```

If you can give me a hand I would appreciate it, if you need for me to post any other part of the code just ask.

Also, I literally just started learning EF Core, so if I did something really stupid, point it out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing empty constructor:

```
public class HealthCheck
{
   // here
   public HealthCheck()
   {
   }

   public HealthCheck(string title, string hctype, string link)
   {
       Title = title;
       HCType = hctype;
       Link = link;
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string HCType { get; set; }
   public string Link { get; set; }


}
```

try it like that

Comment: Thank you! I was sure it had to be something really simple.

Answer (score 18):

Providing a parameterless constructor avoids the problem, but it was not the true cause of the error in the OP's case.  [EF Core 2.1 and higher uses a strict convention to map constructor parameters to property names of the entity.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors)  It expects a constructor parameter's name to be a true camel-case representation of a property name in Pascal-case.  If you change the parameter name from "hctype" to "hCType", you should not get the error and *not* have to provide a parameterless constructor if your approach to domain-driven design dictates that it would be problematic to do so.

If, however, you were simply providing the parameterized constructor as a convenience but it is not improper for a caller to be able to instantiate a HealthCheck with the "new" operator, then simply adding the parameterless constructor is acceptable.

Comment: Based on DDD Is not it better we use "private" access modifier for the parameterless constructor or empty constructor?

Answer (score 4):

I got this exception.

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Blog'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'name' in 'Blog(string name)'; cannot bind 'name' in 'Blog(int id, string name)'.'

I mitigated this in two ways.

First take a look at my Blog class.

```
public class Blog
{
    public Blog(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    private Blog(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; } // Note: No setter, it's a readonly prop. 
    public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new();
}
```

Note there is not setter for Name.

So the first approach was to add private setter. Now its no more a readonly prop. It can be set from within the class.

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

The app ran without exception.

But if you insist on keeping the Name prop readonly here is another way. We need to add and explicit configuration to the context as follows. Here we tell Ef Core to explicitly map it. Ef Core does not map readonly properties by default.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    // Ef does not map readonly properties by default, we have to 
    // ask ef to map the Name even though Name is readonly
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>(b => b.Property(e => e.Name));
}
```

Comment: For the record: this even works with a getter-only property (EF core 5).

Answer (score 0):

As the `HealthCheck` class is representing a **Table** in your database, so you have to provide an empty constructor.
Try the following implementation and let me know if you still receive the same error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Application.Models
{
    public class HealthCheck
    {
        public HealthCheck()
        {
        }

        public HealthCheck(string title, string hctype, string link)
        {
            Title = title;
            HCType = hctype;
            Link = link;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string HCType { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check my answer I wrote that before you, so your answer is exactly same as mine

Answer (score 0):

So many ways of getting this error :-( Here's yet another one:

> read-only properties are not mapped by convention [... even if the PropertyName / constructorParameterNames accurately follow the PascalCase/camelCase matching convention ...], and hence there are no mapped properties that match the constructor. Mapping the properties like this should result in the constructor being used without error:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>(b =>
{
    b.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    b.Property(e => e.Name);                
});
```

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14336

But here is a summary of the rules for ef core as at 2021, which should cover most cans and can'ts:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors