# No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'User'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Im working on a controller for my User model in my aspnet core api. I need a constructor to simplify the post function of the controller.

All works ok, but when I run add-migration on console, it returns the error:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'User'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'username' in 'User(string username, string email, string password)'.

Here is the code for the user model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        
namespace LivetrailsBackend.Models.DataModels
{
    public class User: BaseEntity
    {
        [Required, StringLength(20)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required, EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Trail> Trails { get; set; } = new List<Trail>();
        
        public User(string username, string email, string password)
        {
            UserName = username;
            Email = email;
            Password = password;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the POST methos of the user controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(string username, string email, string password)
{
    if (_context.Users == null)
    {
        return Problem("Entity set 'LivetrailsDBContext.Users'  is null.");
    }

    if (_context.Users.Any(user => user.Email == email))
    {
        return Problem($"That email is already registered.");
    }

    if (_context.Users.Any(user => user.UserName == username))
    {
        return Problem($"Sorry, the username '{username}' is already taken");
    }

    User user = new User(username, email, password);

  
    _context.Users.Add(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
}
```

Comment: Try change constructor parameter `username` to `userName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework expects a constructor parameter's name to be a true camel-case representation of a property name in Pascal-case. So you should change constructor parameter `username` to `userName` to much your property `string UserName { get; set; }`

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57021133/10839134

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

Comment: this answer is kinda similar, albeit not identical, to the most voted one in the already linked in the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838188/system-invalidoperationexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-entity-type